# Residence permit for PhD student

Tags: resident-permit, czech-republic

I am not an EU citizen and currently I am doing a PhD in Switzerland possessing a B permit. I plan to terminate my contract and start PhD anew in Prague (3+ years). As I understood my B permit will be cancelled after termination of my PhD in Switzerland. Should I apply for a student visa, or directly apply for a long-term residence permit?

I am afraid to have a situation when I apply for a student permit, which by some random missing paper may be declined after 2 months and then a new application for long-term permit and/or student permit will result in an extra two month waiting time period, while I am allowed to stay in Czech republic only 90 days after arrival to the country. So, I can easily exceed that 3 month limit which will result in troubles.

Comment: It obviously seems simpler to go directly for the long-term permit, if that is permitted.  Is it permitted?  If so, why would you do otherwise?

Comment: I asked ministry of interior and didn't get clear answer. They offered me to apply for a visa in Vienna (Responsible for Switzerland non-citizen's Visas). And that doesn't make much sense to me. If I am still allowed to travel in EU, pass the border of Czech republic, why can't I directly apply for permit in Czech Republic and need to go to a third country to apply for a visa?!

Comment: Probably because you're supposed to apply for the RP after having moved to CZ, which you won't be able to do after your existing permit is cancelled.  Since they recommended that you apply for a visa, you should probably do that.  Once you move to the country and apply for the RP, most countries allow you to stay after the visa expires, while the permit application is pending.  I expect CZ is the same in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Czech authorities don't care about your Swiss residency permit outside of the scope of short-term travel. Therefore you should apply for a Czech student visa or residency permit. Usually people get a visa first and then change it to a residency permit when inside the country.

You cannot apply for Czech visas or first-time residency permits inside the country, so you'd have to go to Vienna as correctly suggested by the Ministry of Interior.

Comment: You were right. I went to Vienna to apply for the visa.